# Why isn't Line2D.equals overriden?

Tags: java

```
new Line2D.Double(0,0,1,1).equals(new Line2D.Double(0,0,1,1)) // false
```

Why platform designers chose not to override `.equals` on Line2D, but did override it on Point2D?

Comment: My guess would be because it's an abstract class, so that's left to subclasses.  Edit: Never mind, Point2D is also abstract.

Comment: @soong - and subclasses (Line2D.Double or Line2D.Float) also don't override equals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to why the designers of the class chose not to override equals can only be answered by them.

But I will offer my thoughts: there is nothing specifically saying that two lines are **the same line** just because they have the same endpoints.

Consider a program that shows a bunch of random lines bouncing around. If two of them happen to overlap, should they be equal? If I use a Set to keep track of those lines, should I not be able to add another Line that overlaps an existing one?

You can perhaps argue an answer, but I could argue the opposite- which is why they left it up to us to decide for ourselves.

Comment: The counter-case - consider a program that shows a bunch of random points bouncing around. The same reasoning applies - but .equals is overriden, and I would not be able to use Set to keep track of those points.

Comment: @Rogach Okay, and different people make different design decisions. The API was not designed by a single person, so there are going to be differences.

Comment: In my opinion, it would have been nicer if the designers had picked one of the reasonable definitions of `equals()` and save us from extending just for equals in at least some cases. If it doesn't fit our needs, we can always override it.

Comment: @Rob I don't really have a horse in this race. But they did pick a reasonable definition of equals- they picked reference equality.

Comment: _ there is nothing specifically saying that two lines are the same line just because they have the same endpoint_ . Great explanation. +1

Comment: @KevinWorkman - we already have reference equality via `==` and `!=`. When I call `.equals` instead of `==`, I explicitly expect it to do value-based comparison, if at all possible. What you are saying can lead to two outcomes: 1) only implement .equals for immutable classes, and maybe not even for them, 2) never implement `.equals` at all - which is plain strange. I like @200_success's 2nd point much more.

Comment: @Rogach You're arguing against me, but I didn't make these decisions. But only overriding equals() for immutable classes is exactly the argument put forth by many early OOP designers, including Barbara Liskov. This is a pretty fuzzy and subjective question, so you're free to prefer whatever answer you want, but I would perhaps argue that the real reason behind this design decision was a combination of everything we've said, not just one single thing.

Answer (score 3):

We can only speculate.  Two possible reasons:

1. Floating-point equality checks are rarely useful due to inexact values.
2. What would be the expected result from this?

   ```
   new Line2D.Double(0,0,1,1).equals(new Line2D.Double(1,1,0,0))
   ```

   They would *look* the same, but *are* they equal?  Not overriding `.equals()` at all avoids controversy.